# UltraGrid and WebDateChooser

Tags: c#, ultrawingrid

I am using `UltraGrid` in my project. And I am using `WebDateChooser` as a control for one of the column. I want to set `MinDate` and `MaxDate` property to different values in different rows. I am not able to find a way to do it.

Can any one help me out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It will be easier to help you if you share some code with us. How are you creating the UltraGrid and the WebDateChooser? What values are you trying to set MinDate and MaxDate to? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Below is the Row in which a custom control(WebDateChooser) is used.

Comment: <igtbl:UltraGridColumn HeaderText="RequestDate" Key="RDD" Width="65px" DataType="System.DateTime" BaseColumnName="RDD" AllowUpdate="Yes" Type="Custom" EditorControlID="CustomDateChooser2">
<CellStyle Width="65px" />

Comment: Below is the Custom control(WebDateChooser)          
<nc:CustomDateChooser ID="CustomDateChooser2" runat="server" CssClass="DateChooser grid" NullDateLabel="" Text="" Editable="True">
     <ClientSideEvents ValueChanged="Cell_ValueChanged"></ClientSideEvents><DropButton ImageUrl2="../Images/calender.gif" ImageUrl1="../Images/calender.gif" Style-Height="13px" />
      <EditStyle BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="1px"  />
</nc:CustomDateChooser>

Comment: I am trying to set different MinDate and MaxDate for different rows based on other values in the row.